# How can I install a jQuery plugin called "Vegas" on my website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, slider

This is the page I want the slider plugin on: http://game-explorer.webege.com/table.html

This is the plugin link: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

There is a Set Up procedure written. I'm a beginner so a lot of it's aspects are not understandable for me. Can someone guide me or tell me a brief procedure so I can use the plugin on my page. I know it may sound lazy but it isn't, I tried alot but I'm unable to use it!

Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "Set up" guide in the documentation is literally two steps for a basic setup. I'm not sure how anyone could possibly make it simpler to understand.

Comment: Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by you *still* haven't been able to figure out how to *install* Vegas; here you go.

1. You can `download` the plugin's `zip` from the [releases page](https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas/archive/v2.4.0.zip)

   - Download the `zip`, `unzip` the files inside into your directory and make sure that you link your `html` and `css` to the same.
2. Way simpler methods:

   - Using [bower](http://bower.io/): `bower install vegas`
   - Using [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/): `npm install vegas`

And voila!

> Next time, please make an effort to research and make a personal effort before asking a question that has [already been answered](https://github.com/jaysalvat/vegas#install)